Н или НН в причастиях и отглагольных прилагательных
Интересует написание слова РУБЛЕ(Н/НН)ЫЙ в предложении:

Стояло поблизости большое с овином гумно, амбар, два односкатных
сеновала, погреб, баня и рубле(н/нн)ый на студеном ключе колодец.


Надо писать с двумя н, так как это причастие! И точка! Нехрен голову человеку бреднями загромождать! Сначала это отглагольное прилагательное, и так просто оно с одной н пишется (рубленое мясо), а здесь есть зависимые слова, отчего с двумя н.
Стояло поблизости большое с овином гумно, амбар, два односкатных сеновала, погреб, баня и рубленный на студеном ключе колодец.

Правильно:
Стояло поблизости большое с овином гумно, амбар, два односкатных сеновала, погреб, баня и рубленый на студеном ключе колодец.
Пояснение
Рубленый — это согласованное определение, выраженное прилагательным. Однородные отношения с несогласованным определением на студеном ключе (то есть на том месте, где находится ключ).
СЛОВАРИ
Русский орфографический словарь. Рубленый, прил.
Большой толковый словарь русского языка
РУБЛЕНЫЙ, -ая, -ое. 1. Подвергшийся рубке (1.Р.), измельчению. Р-ое мясо. Р-ая капуста. Р. шницель, р-ая котлета (из такого мяса). 2. Бревенчатый. Р-ая стена амбара. Р-ая изба. Р. дом. 3. Короткий, отрывистый (обычно о фразах).

Почему прилагательное, а не причастие?

https://ruscorpora.ru/results?search=ClMqJAoICAAQChgyIAoQBSAAKJKkkbKE4qoCQAVqBDAuOTV4AKABATICCAE6AQFCJAoiCiAKA3JlcRIZChfQoNGD0LHQu9C10L3QvdGL0Lkg0L3QsA==

У них ошибка)  А вы дайте свой ответ.  Я же думаю так (если без Корпуса...). Без зависимых слов это прилагательное с вполне конкретным значением "бревенчатый", А оборот "на студеном ключе" не является зависимым словом для "рубленый", то есть нет значения "рубить/строить на ключе". Но может, оно есть?

Рубленный где? - на студёном ключе - зависимое обстоятельство... Рубленный на. Бревенчатый на студёном ключе колодец - что-то не так... Бревенчатый, на студёном ключе, колодец, - так? На студёном ключе рубленый колодец - ну, возможно...

Ну не знаю... У Белова в 1968 году рубленный. А почему?

Я тогда, тоже не знаю)

Но нет, теперь вы  за все в ответе, с них уже не спросишь)

Кстати, в Карте слов есть современные тексты, где используются оба варианта в совершенно одинаковых конструкциях. Кажется, наши авторы особенно не заморачиваются такими проблемами и пишут на свой вкус  https://kartaslov.ru/предложения-со-словом/рубленный  https://kartaslov.ru/предложения-со-словом/рубленый  Как-то нет порядка в нашей лингвистической науке)

Ну кроме Пирса вроде корректно всё, нет? Хотя у Хеда тоже какая-то белиберда совсем.

Да везде белиберда) Вы им посоветуйте особый отдел организовать для подобной лексики, там профильные специалисты нужны.
